Is tmpfiles.d deleting my core files?
I'm investigating why my core dump files are being deleted on every reboot.  I checked the /etc/tmpfiles.d/ directory and it is empty.  I checked /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf and found:
# Handle lost systemd-coredump temp files. They could be lost on old filesystems,
# for example, after hard reboot.
x  /var/lib/systemd/coredump/.#core*.%b* 
r! /var/lib/systemd/coredump/.#* 

I'm trying to understand the man file, but it looks like the first line says exclude the /var/lib/systemd/coredump/XXX directory altogether.  (I don't understand the .#core.*.%b* syntax).  And the second line says remove empty directories at /var/lib/systemd/coredump/XXX and recurse.  (Again, the suffix I can't explain).
Would either of these two lines be deleting my coredump files on every reboot?  Would I solve the problem by copying the systemd.conf file to /etc/tmpdilfes.d/coredump.conf and change as follows:
x  /var/lib/systemd/coredump/.#core*.%b* 0755 root root 20d
r! /var/lib/systemd/coredump/.#* 0755 root root 20d


This is documented in the tmpfiles.d(5) man page.
The r lines describe files to remove. With the type modifier !, an r! line means the cleanup only happens during boot, not during periodic cleanups. The pattern .#* matches files whose base name starts with the literal two characters .#. Those are temporary files used by systemd (here, by its coredump service), not the actual core dumps (those have a name that doesn't start with .#).
The x lines are exceptions, and they used to not apply to r lines, but they do since systemd v256 (released in June 2024, so still not deployed in most stable distributions). In the path, %b is a specifier that is replaced by a unique identifier that is generated at boot time. So this x line ignores temporary files that were created since the last boot. The intent is to ignore temporary files for a core dump that is being stored at the time the cleanup task runs.
If something is deleting your core files, it's not controlled by those lines of tmpfiles.d.conf. Maybe a different line of the tmpfiles.d configuration applies. Try systemd-tmpfiles --boot --dry-run if your systemd is recent enough, or systemd-tmpfiles --boot --cat-config otherwise. Or maybe it's a different piece of software that's doing it. Also note that if you're trying to look at cores via coredumpctl, it needs the core files to be referenced from the journal.

I'm running ALmaLinux 9 and systemd-tmpfiles does not support --dry-run.  I see a couple of core dumps in the /var/llib/systemd/coredump directory that I created manually , but they don't appear in the list from coredumpctl.  Perhaps that's the problem.  I will wait until the next real core dump to see if it's present after reboot.
